# How to write for Each Loop in Laravel

Tags: laravel

[Laravel Code to connect with Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntmws.jpg)

In $response i have array of items. These items may or may not be present in dishOrder table.

I have to Count the no of orders of each item which is under itemQuantity Column in dishOrder Table.

How to write For Loop for this.?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to loop in blade or in the backend? This is how you generally do loops on arrays / collections.

In backend:

```
foreach( $response as $item ) {
   // do stuff with $item
}
```

If you want to display the count in the frontend

```
@foreach( $response as $item )
    <h1>{{ $item->title }}</h1> <!-- if you have a title -->
    <h2>{{ count( $item->innerArray ) }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ $item->itemQuantity }}</h3>
@endforeach
```

However to be more specific regarding your problem you will need to provide more information or even better the code of what you already tried

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to create an SQL-Query which looks like this in MySQL:

```
SELECT sum(itemQuantity), itemName FROM dishOrder where itemName in ('soup','pizza','burger');
```

Laravel has the whereIn method to create such a query. Example from the manual (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries):

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
                    ->get();
```